# Learning to read haskell in english

Tags: haskell

I come from an object oriented background(C, c++, java) so I am used to being able to read a line of code in english to understand what it is doing.

I am currently doing an adendum to a test in order to recieve extra credit. I have a couple lines of haskell I can't figure out how to read so I cant figure out what they do. I am hoping some one can make them into english sentences.

an example of what I mean as an english sentence would be:

```
i = i + 1
```

i is equal to the contents of i + 1.

or

```
sul ys = all (`elem` ys)
```

the function sul checks all elements of ys for a conditon while checking that a specific element is found in ys, then returning true or false(at least I think thats what it does, the teacher said to ignore the fact that all and `elem` both require two arguments.

the few pieces of code I can't understand are:

```
twasf p = foldr clip [] where
    clip x xs | p x = x : xs 
              | otherwise = []
```

(I dont know how to translate the "|")

```
infixl 5 <*>
xs <*> ys = zipWith ($) xs ys
```

(I have NO idea how to say that)

```
rd []     = []
rd (a:as) = if a `elem` rd as then as else a : rd as
```

(I think this is "Creates an empty list rd, then checks for a in as. if its found then return as, otherwise push a onto the front and return as)

Any help at all would be appreciated. Very willing to read other websites if someone can point me at a website that helps you translate the language.

Comment: i is equal to the contents of i + 1. There's no equality here, that is misleading. I would say `set the contents of i to the contents of i, plus one`

Comment: You know, you can accept an answer by clicking onto the green arrow just below it. This usually makes other people happier to answer your questions.

Answer (score 13):

Part one:

```
    clip x xs | p x = x : xs 
              | otherwise = []
```

> clip: If **p(x)** holds, return x:xs, **otherwise** return the empty list.

```
xs <*> ys = zipWith ($) xs ys
```

> `<*>` applies a list of functions to a list of values.

```
rd []     = []
rd (a:as) = if a `elem` rd as then as else a : rd as
```

Word per word:

> If the list is empty, return the empty list. Else, check if the first element of the list is contained more than once, if so remove it and return the rest of the list. Else return the first element and apply the function recursive to the rest.

Comment: Thank you so much! that got me started :)

Comment: I prefer Damien's substantives as a reading of functional code.

Comment: @luqui: You shuold know, that you should only  downvote, if the answer is *wrong* or not usefull at all. That you find another answer more usefull is usually not a reason to vote down. But it's your reputation.

Comment: @luqui This is the behaviour I see from most people. If you have a look at the absolute vote counts, you see, that most answer have no downvotes at all, only very strange, wrong or off-topic answers have nearly  always downvotes. If you're not shure, feel free to ask at meta about when a downvote is good and when not.

Comment: @luqui the tooltip for the downvote arrow is "This answer is not useful". Do you actually feel it is *not useful* ? Or is it just that you favour a different approach? (I note in passing that the community has settled on agree/disagree as the meaning of voting *on meta* )

Comment: @AakashM, hmmm, the tooltip is the best argument I've seen yet.

Comment: @luqui: Another argument is probably that you will decrease the reputation of the other user by 2 - *punishing him*. Also you will decrease your own rep by 1. Should a user be *punished* just because you like another answer more?

Comment: @FUZxxl, 2 points is a drop in the bucket for most users -- it's approximately equivalent to the severity of a drive-by argument.

Comment: @luqui: I don't wan't to continue this discussion here. By the upvotes of my comments, you can see, that I'm possible not the only onw with this opinion.

Comment: @FUZxxl, ok, sorry for being a donkey about it.  Separating each comment by a day somehow diluted my natural "let it go" check.

Answer (score 9):

Haskell is purely functional, so you can't really say "creates, then checks and does such and such". Substantives apply better.

For the last example I guess `rd` is for removing duplicates, so I'd say the duplicate removal…

- of the empty list: is the empty list;
- of an `a:as` list: is the remainder `as` if `a` was in `as`, or `a` followed by the recursive duplicate removal otherwise.

BTW. shouldn't last line be …`if a elem as then rd as else`… ?

Comment: …and that's why I have such a hard time wrapping my mind around functional programs, because they read like math equations full of passive voice. Sequential stories with characters (i.e. OO programs) work better than for me. Anyone else get that impression?

Answer (score 6):

Let's look at these one-at-a-time.

1. The pipe syntax indicates a *guard*, which you can think of as similar to an if-else ladder. I would read it as "If `p` of `x` is true, then return `x` concatenated onto `xs`, otherwise return the empty list".
2. The first line says "`<*>` is an left-associative infix operator with precedence 5" (you'll have to come up with your own pronunciation for `<*>` - often in this sort of thing I'd just think of it as "op"). The next line is "xs op ys is the same as xs zipped with ys, using the function application operator `$`".
3. This is an example of a function having multiple definitions. The way it works is that if the first "pattern" of arguments matches, that definition is used, and if not, it falls down to any other definitions. In this case, I would read it as "rd of an empty list is an empty list, otherwise (etc.)"

You'd probably benefit from reading through a Haskell tutorial or two, which will help get you familiar with the syntax and way of thinking about Haskell - for example, check out http://learnyouahaskell.com/.

Comment: I usually pronounce "`<*>`" as "ap", since it serves the same purpose as the `ap` function in Control.Monad.

Answer (score 3):

If you have to do more Haskell in the future, the book [Programming in Haskell](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~gmh/book.html) is a pretty concise and nice introduction, that also tells you how to properly read Haskell. Here's an example from the book:

```
abs n |n >= 0     = n 
      | otherwise = −n
```

> The symbol | is read as “such that”,
>   and the guard otherwise is defined in
>   the standard prelude simply by
>   otherwise = True.